# Java setter and instance -- Change a variable

Tags: java, setter

I'm trying to learn how to change an instance once it's already created.  I have a constructor with a loop that prints my setting variable.  The variable setting starts as 0 being upset, and the loop loops until the setting variable aren't 0.  My obviously wrong expectations were that:

1. A new instance would be created named object.
2. The loop would run because the setting variable is 0.
3. The setting variable would be changed to 1.
4. The loop would stop.

I Ask:

1. Why isn't my while loop using the updated variable "setting"?
2. Is this the correct way to something that already instantiated?
3. If there's a better way please leave an example so I can learn.

   ```
   public class test2 extends Thread {
       private int setting;   

       public void setSetting(int input) {
           this.setting = input;
       }

       public test2() {        
           while (setting == 0) {
               System.out.println(setting);
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           test2 object = new test2();
           object.setSetting(1);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Because the loop never exits the constructor.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in your debugger as this show show you what the issues very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A new instance would be created named object.
>   
> The loop would run because the setting variable is 0.

Yes. You are correct.

> The setting variable would be changed to 1.

This is not true because the loop in the constructor is still running and control hasn't returned from the constructor and hence the next statement `object.setSetting(1);` isn't executed.

You can achieve this by creating two Threads. One will loop till the variable is 0 and the other would set it to some value.
However, you cannot have that loop in the constructor as you need the fully constructed *object* to be shared between these two threads.
(Note: In this case, you need to have the field `setting` as **volatile** for the changes to become visible to the second thread).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I surely would have missed the volatile part!  Lots of reading ahead :)